# Get list from lists in java?

Tags: java, list

First, I need to say that I tried found explanation in internet, but all are unclear for me.

I worte a program in java FX. One of classes has method generating two list:

```
listA = [0,2,3,4,1,2,5,12,3,2,1,3]
listB = [2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]
```

I need to return that lists so I connect it in one:

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        result.add(listA);
        result.add(listB);
        return(result);
```

head of that method looks that:

```
static public List man() { #could be usefull to explain me how to fix my code.
```

So now in another class i call the method:

```
List newList= classTest.man();
```

And print it:

```
System.out.println(newList);
```

So I got:

```
[[0,2,3,4,1,2,5,12,3,2,1,3][2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]]
```

And it's fine, I just want a write a loop to fill data for my chart:

```
for(int i; i < newList.get(0).length(); i++){
  String iterationNum= Integer.toString(newList.get(0).get(i);
  series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(iterationNum; newList.get(0).get(i)));
```

But first:

```
1. .length() is red : error = "Cannot resolve symbol 'length'"

2. in newList.get(0).get(i) the second .get(i) is red. error = "Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Object'"
```

Please, can someone help me solve my problem? I wrote almost whole of program, and stuck here.

Comment: are you looking for `.size()` ? instead of `length`

Comment: thanks for reply .size() cause: Cannot resolve method 'size' in 'Object'.
So maybe it's something wrong with my array?

Comment: Also, don't use raw types.  `static public List man()` should probably be something like `static public List<List<Integer>> man()`.

Comment: If the number of Lists will always be two you should consider creating a class which would have two fields `listA` and `listB` and use that as a result instead of using List of list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ".length" is used to determine the Length of an array. For lists you use ".size()"
2. Try replacing it with `((List<Integer>) newList.get(0)).get(i);`

Comment: @martin `int j = 0;`

Comment: Yeah I noticed it while after reply! :)
Thank U ! Ur suggestion was very good. All works!

Answer (score 3):

> length is red : error = "Cannot resolve symbol 'length'"

`.length` is used to get the length of an array. You are using, I assume, `java.util.List`. You need to use the method `size`, e.g. `newList.get(0).size()`

> in newList.get(0).get(i) the second .get(i) is red. error = "Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Object'"

`static public List man()` I'm not sure what this method does, but you are using a raw type. This means that the `List` you are getting back is basically equivalent to `List<Object>`.

So you are trying to call `Object#get(i)`, and `get` is not a valid method on an Object. You need to specify what type `List man()` will return. For instance, `List<Integer> man()`, or whatever type it needs to be. I can't tell from your code what you're actually doing.